# Unable to populate zend form through ajax request

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

I am trying to populate a zend form by executing a jquery post request on click of a link. I pass the id to the js function so that my action knows which data to populate but the values don't get populated. The values were being popualated when i was passing the id parameter through URL

JS call

```
<a href="javascript: edit(id)">
```

JS function

```
function edit(id)
{
    $.post("url",{'edit':id});

}
```

inside zend action

```
 if ($this->_request->getParam('edit')) {
                 $id=$this->_request->getParam('edit');
                 $table=$Table->findByID($id);
                 $table->populateForm();

             }
```

**Edit**

I was able to populate the form and render it on the page by setting the data type of my ajax call to html and passing the populated zend form to the ajax call in the controller
Controller:
`echo $form; exit;`
Ajax call
`success: function(data){ $(#div).html(data)}`

Make sure that the data type of your ajax call is html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to populate the form and render it on the page by setting the data type of my ajax call to html and passing the populated zend form to the ajax call in the controller

Controller: 
`echo $form; exit;`

Ajax call 
`success: function(data){ $(#div).html(data)}`

Make sure that the data type of your ajax call is html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function edit(id)
{
    $.get("url",{'edit':id});
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use get..i want this data to pass through post request only

Answer (score 0):

Inside your action i think you need a little bit more code then that

```php
$id    = $this->_request->getParam('edit', NULL);

if(FALSE === is_null($id)) {

     $form      = new Form(); //unless this is created somewhere else
     $data      = $Table->findByID($id); //$table and $Table is bit confusing

     $form->populate($data); 
     /*
     or if $table->populateForm(); does this for you make sure you 
     pass the result data 
     $table->populateForm($data);
     */  
 }
```

Comment: form is already created somewhere else and this is not working either. I am using a similar implementation for delete and it works. I think its something to do with the ajax request. I think I cannot ouput any data outside ajax for an ajax call. Correct me if m wrong

Answer (score 0):

If it was working thru get but not post it might be leading zeros or something in the typing of $id.

Specially if your $Table->findByID do some casting.

try:

```
 if ($this->_request->getParam('edit')) {
                 $id= (int) $this->_request->getParam('edit');
                 $table=$Table->findByID($id);
                 $table->populateForm();

             }
```

if that doesn't work try debugging  your $this->_request->getParam('edit') from post and get and see whats the difference between em.

But if your exemple was working with get it must work with post.

Comment: please tell me whether it is possible to set values of form using `form->setValue()` method during an ajax request